# parse array contains 6 bits of data, i want to parse each part and put it into its own array so i can find averages etc

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing

Each part of my array has 6 bits of data shown here

```
   83   0   0   -1  0   50
   83   0   0   -1  0   50
   85   0   0   -1  0   50
   87   0   0   -1  0   50
   89   0   0   -1  0   50
```

i need to parse each one into a new array so i can then go on to find averages and more.
the first colum is heartrate the second is speed and is to the power of 10 so will need to be in some sort of decimal i was thinking floating point. cheers for any help

this is what ive got so far

```
        int[] hrDataList = new int[5];
        string[] seperator = { "\t" };
        for (int i = 0; i < hrDataList.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] temp = hrDataList[i].ToString().Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.None);

            heartrate[i] = int.Parse(temp[0]);
            speed[i] = int.Parse(temp[1]);
            cad[i] = int.Parse(temp[2]);
            alt[i] = int.Parse(temp[3]);
            pwr[i] = int.Parse(temp[4]);
            pwrbal[i] = int.Parse(temp[5]);

        }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: my text document is massive and split into different segments this is the most important one, each segment is split byt [] brackets this link shows you what ive done so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957559/trying-to-write-a-c-program-that-parses-a-text-file-that-contains-data-seperated

Comment: @RoboCod101, I see. I posted an answer in yesterday's question of yours.

Comment: cheers for your help yesterday

Comment: below users a jagged array is there a way without using a jagged array as i cant get it working

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
            int[] thearray = new int[5];
        int[][] thenewarray = new int[5][];
        string[] seperator = { "\t" };
        for (int i = 0; i < thearray.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] temp = thearray[i].ToString().Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int[] toadd = new int[temp.Length];
            thenewarray[i] = new int[temp.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.Length; j++)
            {
                thenewarray[i][j] = int.Parse(temp[j]);
            }
        }
```

Tested and works.

Comment: hi ive almost got this working but it only puts it into 1 new array i was hoping to split it into 6 new arrays how would i do this?

Comment: The new array is a jagged array. each row is in and of itself an array. It is literally an array of arrays.

Comment: it seems to get stuck at heartRateData[i][j] = int.Parse(temp[j]);ive been trying for the last hour to get it to work

Comment: is there a way without using a jagged array?

Comment: Use a 2d array declared uptop

Comment: Posted revised code that works (sorry, forgot a line in the origonal)